# For a column in pandas dataframe, calculate mean of column values in previous 4th, 8th and 12th row from the present row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

In a pandas dataframe, I want to create a new column that calculates the average of column values of 4th, 8th and 12th row **before** our present row.

As shown in the table below, for row number 13 :

Value in **Existing column** that is 4 rows before row 13 (row 9) = 4

Value in **Existing column** that is 8 rows before row 13 (row 5) = 6

Value in **Existing column** that is 12 rows before row 13 (row 1) = 2

Average of 4,6,2 is 4. Hence **New Column = 4** at row number 13, for the remaining rows between 1-12, **New Column = Nan**

I have more rows in my df, but I added only first 13 rows here for illustration.

| Row number | Existing column | New column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 2 | 4 | NaN |
| 3 | 3 | NaN |
| 4 | 1 | NaN |
| 5 | 6 | NaN |
| 6 | 4 | NaN |
| 7 | 8 | NaN |
| 8 | 2 | NaN |
| 9 | 4 | NaN |
| 10 | 9 | NaN |
| 11 | 2 | NaN |
| 12 | 4 | NaN |
| 13 | 3 | 3 |

Comment: Any clarification required for my answer ?  Please let me know if any fine-tuning to meet your requirement is needed.

Comment: Thank you SeaBean! This totally worked for my requirement. How can I tweak this approach to obtain the median for the same values in addition to average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) is your missing part.  We can use it to access previous rows from the existing row in a Pandas dataframe.

Let's use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) as follows:

```
df['New column'] = df.groupby((df['Row number'] - 1) // 13)['Existing column'].apply(lambda x: (x.shift(4) + x.shift(8) + x.shift(12)) / 3)
```

Here, rows are partitioned into groups of 13 rows by grouping them under different group numbers set by `(df['Row number'] - 1) // 13`

Then within each group, we use `.apply()` on the column `Existing column` and use `.shift()` to get the previous 4th, 8th and 12th entries within the group.

### Test Run

```
data = {'Row number' : np.arange(1, 40), 'Existing column': np.arange(11, 50) }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

    Row number  Existing column
0            1               11
1            2               12
2            3               13
3            4               14
4            5               15
5            6               16
6            7               17
7            8               18
8            9               19
9           10               20
10          11               21
11          12               22
12          13               23
13          14               24
14          15               25
15          16               26
16          17               27
17          18               28
18          19               29
19          20               30
20          21               31
21          22               32
22          23               33
23          24               34
24          25               35
25          26               36
26          27               37
27          28               38
28          29               39
29          30               40
30          31               41
31          32               42
32          33               43
33          34               44
34          35               45
35          36               46
36          37               47
37          38               48
38          39               49

df['New column'] = df.groupby((df['Row number'] - 1) // 13)['Existing column'].apply(lambda x: (x.shift(4) + x.shift(8) + x.shift(12)) / 3)

print(df)

    Row number  Existing column  New column
0            1               11         NaN
1            2               12         NaN
2            3               13         NaN
3            4               14         NaN
4            5               15         NaN
5            6               16         NaN
6            7               17         NaN
7            8               18         NaN
8            9               19         NaN
9           10               20         NaN
10          11               21         NaN
11          12               22         NaN
12          13               23        15.0
13          14               24         NaN
14          15               25         NaN
15          16               26         NaN
16          17               27         NaN
17          18               28         NaN
18          19               29         NaN
19          20               30         NaN
20          21               31         NaN
21          22               32         NaN
22          23               33         NaN
23          24               34         NaN
24          25               35         NaN
25          26               36        28.0
26          27               37         NaN
27          28               38         NaN
28          29               39         NaN
29          30               40         NaN
30          31               41         NaN
31          32               42         NaN
32          33               43         NaN
33          34               44         NaN
34          35               45         NaN
35          36               46         NaN
36          37               47         NaN
37          38               48         NaN
38          39               49        41.0
```

Comment: Thank you SeaBean! This totally worked for my requirement. How can I tweak this approach to obtain the median for the same values in addition to average?

Comment: @srikarmalladi To get the median, you can use `df['New column'] = df.groupby((df['Row number'] - 1) // 13)['Existing column'].transform(lambda x: [np.nan] * 12 + [x.iloc[[0, 4, 8]].median()])`  You can also replace `.median()` in this code by `.mean()` to get the mean.

Comment: @srikarmalladi  If you use my sample data, you may find the median and mean has the same value.  There is no problem.  It is because just by co-incidence the mean and median have the same values.  You can test it with other set of data.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `rolling` with `.apply` to apply a custom aggregation function.
2. The average of (4,6,2) is 4, not 3

```
>>> (2 + 6 + 4) / 3
4.0
```

```
>>> df["New column"] = df["Existing column"].rolling(13).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0, 4, 8]].mean())
>>> df
    Row number  Existing column  New column
0            1                2         NaN
1            2                4         NaN
2            3                3         NaN
3            4                1         NaN
4            5                6         NaN
5            6                4         NaN
6            7                8         NaN
7            8                2         NaN
8            9                4         NaN
9           10                9         NaN
10          11                2         NaN
11          12                4         NaN
12          13                3         4.0
```

breaking it down:

- `df["Existing column"]`: select "Existing column" from the dataframe
- `.rolling(13)`: starting with the first 13 rows, we're going to move a sliding window across all of the data. So first, we will encounter rows 0-12, then rows 1-13, then 2-14, so on and so forth.
- `.apply(...)`: For each of those aforementioned rolling sections, we're going to apply a function that works on each section (in this case the function we're applying is the lambda.
- `lambda x: x.iloc[[0, 4, 8]].mean()`: from each of those rolling sections, extract the 0th 4th, and 8th (corresponding to row 1, 5, & 9) and calculate and return the mean of those values.

---

In order to work on your dataframe in chunks (or groups) instead of a sliding window, you can apply the same logic with the `.groupby` method (instead of `.rolling`).

```
>>> groups = np.arange(len(df)) // 13 # defines groups as chunks of 13 rows
>>> averages = (
        df.groupby(groups)["Existing column"]
        .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0, 4, 8]].mean())
    )
>>> averages.index = (averages.index + 1) * 13 - 1
>>> df["New column"] = averages
>>> df
    Row number  Existing column  New column
0            1                2         NaN
1            2                4         NaN
2            3                3         NaN
3            4                1         NaN
4            5                6         NaN
5            6                4         NaN
6            7                8         NaN
7            8                2         NaN
8            9                4         NaN
9           10                9         NaN
10          11                2         NaN
11          12                4         NaN
12          13                3         4.0
```

breaking it down now:

- `groups = np.arange(len(df))`: creates an array that will be used to chunk our dataframe into groups. This array will essentially be 13 0s, followed by 13 1s, follow by 13 2s... until the array is the same length as the dataframe. So in this case for a single chunk example it will only be an array of 13 0s.
- `df.groupby(groups)["Existing column"]` group the dataframe according to the groups defined above and select the "Existing column"
- `.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0, 4, 8]].mean())`: Conceptually the same as before, except we're applying to each grouping instead of a sliding window.
- `averages.index = (averages.index + 1) * 12`: this part may seem a little odd. But we're essentially ensuring that our selected averages line up with the original dataset correctly. In this case, we want the average from group 0 (specified with an index value of 0 in the `averages` Series) to align to row 12. If we had another group (group 1, we would want it to align to row 25 in the original dataset). So we can use a little math to do this transformation.
- `df["New column"] = averages`: since we already matched up our indices, pandas takes care of the actual alignment of these new values under the hood for us.

Comment: Thank you for your solution Cameron! Very much appreciate your help here. However, for the next 12 rows after 13th row i.e., 14th to 25th row - my values in New column should again be NaN and value in the 26th row should be average of row 22nd, row 18 and row 14. In other words, I have partitions of 13 rows and mean has to be calculated only within that partition for 4th, 8th and 12th row before the 13th row

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. Let me edit my answer.